# How to close an html website using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

So basically, I'm trying to create a system that closing the website when you get the password wrong. but I started to learn js just a couple of days ago and I don't know much of it yet.

here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html id="web" lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>MySite</title>
    <script>
        var web = document.getElementById("web");
        var password = "BigDips12";
        alert("Hey, For security messures and to make sure you are truly not a robot ...");
        var security = prompt("Please enter the password here:");
        if (security === password) {
            alert('Welcome!')
        } else {
            alert('Password is wrong! The program will close itself now..')

            function closeWin() {
                web.close();
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

I really need help pls

Comment: Instead of closing the website you can redirect that back to google or something like that, so you can use `window.location.href = "https://google.com";` when they enter the incorrect password

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please clarify what you mean by "*closing the website*" Do you mean redirecting to a Login Page again? or Closing the browser window?

Comment: If you did not create the window with window.open, you can not close it.

Comment: @Spectric I know I know its just for learning...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close the browser tab use

```
window.close();
```

And u wasn't calling the function also

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html id="web" lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>MySite</title>
  <script>
  function closeWin() {
        window.close();
      }
    var web = document.getElementById("web");
    var password = "BigDips12";
    alert("Hey, For security messures and to make sure you are truly not a robot ...");
    var security = prompt("Please enter the password here:");
    if (security === password) {
      alert('Welcome!')
    } else {
      alert('Password is wrong! The program will close itself now..')
   closeWin()
      
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by them.